# Chamar modal via url

Tags: javascript, url

Tenho uma página na qual existe um `Modal` de cadastro, tenho que chamar este modal a partir de uma pagina externa, preferencialmente por `url`, gostaria de saber se é possível e se podem me indicar o caminho

> OBS: O `Modal` não pode ser habilitado diretamente na página, e esta página utiliza o `Bootstrap` para gerar os `Modai's`.

Comment: Esta URL externa será inserida por outra pessoa remotamente?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor "chamar este modal a partir de uma pagina externa"? portanto a página tem a possibilidade de mostrar um modal mas só o faz se o URL o pedir? tipo Query string? `minhapagina.html?modal=true` -> abre e `minhapagina.html` -> não abre?

Comment: é um link externo, ele passa um método `GET` e com isso mostrar o modal

Comment: então queres ler a querystring no JS para saber se o modal deve abrir? é isso?

Comment: @sergio sim isso mesmo

Comment: ok, vou dar uma resposta mas podes dar mais uma indicação: qual é o aspeto dessa url quando deve chamar o modal? tem alguma chave para o modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para leres a query string (GET) num URL podes fazer uma funçao assim:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Neste caso se tiveres um url `minhapagina.html?modal=true` então `getParameterByName('modal)` var dar `true`.

Esta função [fui buscar ao SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/2256325) mas pode ser que nem precises de algo assim, se o url que ativa a modal não tiver pares de chave/valor e somente `?modal` ou nada; então um `.indexOf()` basta.

Neste caso podes usar `location.search.indexOf('modal') != -1` que vai dar verdadeiro (`true`) caso a palavra "modal" exista na parte `?xxxx` do url.